# Problem: Smarty get error when variable does not exist

Tags: php, smarty

I want smarty do not continue processing when some variable does not exist. Like in foreach lopp, in echo and etc. What should i do ?! (Example: I am displaying all orders in a page, When No order exists What should i do with No array in output and Smarty Error on foreach loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so just predefine it

```
$array = array();
```

Comment: @MemphisRaines: no it isn't possible

Comment: What should i do with simple variables?! if i set them Null, it get error again, I afraid about writing extra codes...

Comment: @MemphisRaines: define them as an array()

Comment: Thats a good idea, i should check and check it won't get any bug... TNX